# How Many Stones to Place on a Grave?

Tags: minhag, number, kavod, cemetery-grave

When visiting a gravesite, my Jewish relatives always place small stones on the gravestone as a showing of respect for the dead.  They typically place one stone on the gravestone,  but I find myself wondering how many stones is a visitor expected to place on a gravestone.  Is there a minimum or maximum count?  Is it considered disrespectful to place too many or too few?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/placing-stones-on-a-grave

Comment: @gershongold: Thank you for the link to the other question.  I did see that but didn't find the answer there.  It is focused on *why* stones are placed on the gravestone,  not *how many*,  However,  the question is closely related and I hope it helps to clarify what I am trying to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Orach Chaim 224:12 Beer Haitaiv 8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=721) says the reason that either grass or stone is placed on the grave is as a honor for the person buried there, as it shows that people came to his grave. There is no mention as to placing more than or less than one.

Comment: One stone shows that one person came one time to pay their respects. There is no reason to inflate that number. (And I don't think there's an obligation to leave that mark if you don't consider your visit "significant".) So: Minimum 0, maximum 1.