# Vicariously placing stones on a grave

Tags: cemetery-grave, shlichus-agency

Can a kohen, or someone who will not have the opportunity to visit a grave for that matter, ask someone who will be visiting a grave to put stones there for him?

Comment: see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4057/placing-stones-on-a-grave. What do you think that this accomplished that might not be able to be accomplished by proxy?

Comment: Did you really mean "Can"? I mean, why can't he?

Comment: @msh210, I have no clue why he couldn't however, as Matt's above quoted question (which inspired this one) points out, it is an action of respect and of building up the kever. I do not know whether the intention of the action affects that. I would figure that their is no problem, but halachot and minhagim relating to the deceased are far from my area of expertise.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt, okay, just checking that you really meant to ask "Can" and not something like "Should".